# Xpath for any html element containing specific text inside html tag

Tags: xpath

Need to find xpath that matches any html tag that contains the word sidebar in any html tag. Example:

```
<p class='my class'>This is some text</p>
<h1 class='btn sidebar btn-now'><p>We have more text here</p><p> and anoter text here</p></div>
<div id='something here'>New text here</div>
<div id='something sidebar here'>New text again</div>
<nav class='this sidebar btn'>This is my nav</nav>
<sidebar><div>This is some text</div></sidebar>
```

I need xpath to get any html element that has word 'sidebar' between starting < and ending > html tag, be it class, id or html tag name. In the above example I need to get as result:

```
 <h1 class='btn sidebar btn-now'><p>We have more text here</p><p> and anoter text here</p></div>
<div id='something sidebar here'>New text again</div>
<nav class='this sidebar btn'>This is my nav</nav>
<sidebar><div>This is some text</div></sidebar>
```

Needs to be xpath not regex

Comment: Should it also find `<a href="sidebar">`, `<div data-sidebar="foo">`, `<p class="sideb&#97;r">`?

Comment: @melpomene yes, html tag that has sidebar inside <  >

Comment: The last one doesn't have `sidebar` in its HTML code.

Comment: the <sidebar> tag (is not an valid html tag, was just as an example) but basically if it would exists then everything between <sidebar> and </sidebar> should match. I can remove that from my above example if you thing it's not ok there

Comment: I was talking about my examples, not yours. `<p class="sideb&#97;r">` does not contain `sidebar`. Do you want it to be found or not?

Comment: aaa, NO, but if class is sidebarfoo, or foosidebar, or foosidebarfoo, then in this cases yes

Comment: Your problem cannot be solved with XPath.

Comment: ok, but in case if class="sideb&#97;r" would be correct answer, how would the xpath solution look like

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below and let me know if it's not what you're searching for:

```
//*[contains(@*, "sidebar") or contains(name(), "sidebar")]
```

- `contains(@*, "sidebar")` means node with *any attribute* that contains `"sidebar"`
- `contains(name(), "sidebar")` - node name that contains `"sidebar"`

If you need only `id` or `class` to contain `"sidebar"`:

```
//*[contains(@id, "sidebar") or contains(@class, "sidebar") or contains(name(), "sidebar")]
```

Comment: Does this check both attribute names and attribute values?

Comment: Attribute values only. Do you need attribute names also? If so, add `or contains(@*/name(), "sidebar")` predicate